# Ito Isometry under conditional expectation

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, stochastic-integrals

Consider the process $X_t$, where:
$$X_t \equiv X(t) - X(t-1) = \int_{t-1}^{t} \sigma(s) \, dW(s).$$
I want to obtain an expression for the conditional variance of $X_t$, i.e. $var(X_t|\mathcal{F}_{t-1})$.
So far my attempt is:
$$var(X_t|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}) = E\left[\left(\int_{t-1}^t \sigma(s)\,dW(s) \right)^2 | \mathcal{F}_{t-1} \right] = E\left[\int_{t-1}^t \sigma^2(s)\,ds | \mathcal{F}_{t-1} \right]$$
by the Ito Isometry. However, I am not sure that Ito Isometry can be exploited in the conditional expectation framwork.

Comment: Is $\sigma(s)$ a deterministic function, or a stochastic process?

Comment: $\sigma$ is a predictable process

Comment: You are using Ito isometry correctly. Hint. It follows from the martingale property of the square of the stochastic integral minus its quadratic variation.